# Xaml TextBlock Width inconsistent behavior

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml, data-binding

Please look 5 min at this simple bug :

```
<textblock (...) Width="0" />
```

Working great, the textBox appears to be 0px thin. Works with value like, 2, 3, 4...

Now that is NOT working :

```
<TextBlock (...) />
    <TextBlock.Width>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource WidthConverter}">
             <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                   <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                   <Binding RelativeSource="{x:Static RelativeSource.Self}" Path="TemplatedParent.Parent.ActualWidth"  />
              </MultiBinding.Bindings>
         </MultiBinding>
    <TextBlock.Width>
</TextBlock>
```

```vb
Public Class WidthConverter
    Implements IMultiValueConverter

        Public Function Convert(ByVal values() As Object, ByVal targetType As System.Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IMultiValueConverter.Convert

        Return 0
    End function
end class
```

why can i set zero value to TextBox.Width in xaml and not in code behind ?

By using a converter, when returing 0, the TextBlock.Width is not set to 0 but to "auto", i can read the text

Comment: *How* is it not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property is of type `double`, you return an `int`, change it to `return 0.0` and it should work.

*(The reason being that bindings set properties via reflection, and there is no implicit conversion in that, so if you return an `int` that is considered to be not a number and `double.NaN` is the value used to describe the `Auto` behavior)*